# How to query the erc20 balance of an address using eth-cli command?

Tags: balances, cli, eth-cli

How does one get the balance of tokens erc20 of an address when using the eth-cli command?

Answer (score 1):

For example, with [USDC](https://etherscan.io/token/0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48) at address `0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48` and with the aim of checking the balance of address `0xf16e9b0d03470827a95cdfd0cb8a8a3b46969b91` :

```
npx eth-cli repl --mainnet erc20@0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48
mainnet> erc20.methods.balanceOf("0xf16e9b0d03470827a95cdfd0cb8a8a3b46969b91")
```

Outputs the current balance of the requested address : 6051828199681

Comment: how to format that decimal place output?